# This iPhone 6 Plus is running iOS 10.3.2 (14F89), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

Im trying to run my react native app on my iOS device, but I'm getting an error in `Xcode`

> This iPhone 6 Plus is running iOS 10.3.2 (14F89), which may not be
>   supported by this version of Xcode

My MacBook OS is running the latest OS version and so is `Xcode`

Comment: Can you add what versions they are?

Comment: What xcode and macOS version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just get new Xcode here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12 .